# New session starts on every request in IIS Express, Hosting environment works fine

Tags: asp.net, wcf, session, iis-8

Production application losses session values on every request in IIS Express only. This issue occurs after some security update on windows 10.Its a client side Application uses Inproc session with cookie and WCF Service calls.
Issue occurs in all updated browsers.Session works fine for lower versions of browsers like IE 9 but IE 10 and 11 creates new session.